# Does life have to evolve into animals, plants and fungi?

Tags: biology, evolution, xenobiology

When we go into speculative biology for worldbuilding, we often go straight to thinking about how animals and plants might evolve. I wanted to know if there is a good reason for that, or if it's just for simplicity's sake.

Does life have to take the route of first evolving basic phytoplankton and zooplankton and from there organisms that expand on that sessile autotrophic and motile heterotrophic lifestyle? Do all planets with complex, multi-cellular life end up having organisms that greatly resemble our plants and our animals in terms of their biology and lifestyle?

There are fungi on Earth, which don't fit in either because of their cell structure. There's also chromista and a couple others, but I don't know much about them. That made me think, are there other possibilities when it comes to things like cell structure and lifestyles that would make life on other planets look nothing alike to that on Earth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It depends on your definitions:**

Life doesn't need to be plants, animals, and fungi. But depending on how you make you definitions, it also kinda does.

The defining characteristics of plants are that they produce their own food from an energy source (autotrophs). The form of this energy can vary from planet to planet, but light is an ideal source (literally raining from the heavens). There are chemoautotrophs, but renewable chemical energy is a lot harder to come by. So it's difficult to have a life system without plants or the near equivalent.

Fungi absorb nutrients from their environment, either breaking down existing food or parasitizing plants and animals. As a general rule, they are non-motile, saving energy expended in motion for growth. The simplicity and efficiency of this approach would naturally tend to reoccur wherever there is available exploitable food in the environment.

Animals consume other organisms directly, and are generally motile (sponges are animals, and only motile during a narrow part of the life cycle, but still). It's an extremely powerful ability, being able to exploit other organisms and their resources for the energy needed to live. But to be motile, you need to consume a lot of energy.

So while you don't NEED plants, animals, and fungi, the ROLES of these organisms are straightforward and highly logical. If you don't have your dominant multicellular life doing THESE things, you need to do some justification as to why they AREN'T. Simplicity is key, and if you try to come up with a complex arrangement that doesn't follow these rules, why aren't organisms evolving that DO follow them, and outcompete the alternatives?

Comment: One little point is that the roles could theoretically blend.  It seems possible that some alien biosphere may evolve species that straddle any taxonomic line we've drawn here on Earth.  For example maybe an organism that can walk or swim around, but also does photosynthesis.  Or a stationary organism that does photosynthesis, like a plant, but has no cell wall, only a cell membrane like an animal.

Comment: @Ryan_L: Though in Earthlike environments, plant-equivalents pretty well have to be non-motile (or very slow moving), because they need a large surface area to capture energy.  But of course there are predatory plants (e.g. the Venus Flytrap), parasitic plants, and things like the Snow Plant that are parasites on the mycorrhizal  fungi that have a symbiotic relationship with pine trees: https://www.fs.fed.us/wildflowers/plant-of-the-week/sarcodes_sanguinea.shtml

Answer (score 5):

Does life have to evolve into animals, plants and fungi? No it does not. A huge amount depends on the environment and the evolutionary pressures involved. No plants are likely to evolve in the dark and mobility might be seriously hindered on a high gravity world.

But assuming a world very similar to ours it’s probably at least a likely as the conditions and evolutionary pressures would be the same. It’s hard to know exactly how likely given all of the variables so we can’t be too proscriptive but I suggest that at the very least any large animal based on direct photosynthesis would probably be at a huge disadvantage due to the energy required for movement.

I should also point out that the kingdoms of Monera (archaebacteria) and Protista (algae and protozoa) also exist in addition to the animal plant and fungi kingdoms and in another version of Earth may have taken on different roles.

If truly alien biochemistries are to be considered then the scope is almost infinite and only limited by the scope of chemistry itself which is truly immense beyond belief. In fact I suggest that the chemicals currently known to man are likely to be outnumbered by those unknown possibilities by many orders of magnitude. So the ultimate scope of the possible remains obscure in this vastness.

Comment: The vast majority of simpler chemicals is known and has been synthesised. I strongly doubt that there are any larger gaps. Larger molecules in an alien biochemistry will also be polymeric, because that's more efficient, and efficiency wins in evolution. And the smaller the building blocks, the better a head start a given system will have in reality. Ergo: You'll very, very likely end up with sugars and lipids and peptides, because alternatives are too complicated.

Comment: @Karl It depends what you mean by simpler chemicals. Less than 10 atoms and you might be right. More than 30 and you are certainly wrong. Biochemistry is fiendishly complex and involves huge numbers of polymeric and non polymeric chemicals (https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/technical-documents/articles/biology/interactive-metabolic-pathways-map.html). Even with amino acids only 20 of more than 500 known amino acids are found in our biochemistry and biology does not use the simplest 20. Each of them also occur in at least 2 optical isomers and there are millions of possible lipids

Comment: Well, these https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aminos%C3%A4uren#/media/Datei:Aminosaeuren.png *are* pretty small and simple. You need a good range of chemical functionality anyway, and nature covers that very efficiently. What I meant to say is that a biochemistry based on something *else* than simple amino acids etc. is highly unlikely to evolve.

Comment: @Karl a number of these are also small and simple with a good range of functionality but they are not on your list https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/chemistry/chemistry-products.html?TablePage=16274965 How do you know that biochemistry based on something else is highly unlikely? We only have one example of biogenesis to go on. If conditions were different I suspect that life would have used whatever was available. Thiolins, chitosan and many other compounds could probably be pressed into service

Comment: I only wanted to say that an alien amino acid biochemistry would likely contain a very similar range of amino acids. Disregarding absolute configuration, I say 80% overlap. And a biochemistry that is based on a different set of *classes* of chemicals is extremely speculative. For starters it has to work with, or avoid, gaseous oxygen. Earth has a wide range of surface temperatures, so will any other inhabitable planet. The first biochemistry that produces *life* anywhere on a planet will take over, because it allows for evolution. The rest gets eaten.

Comment: I believe ours is what we have  because it simply is the fastest solution, and if that's true, it's going to win every time a planet cools into the habitable region, again. Maybe there is one other system with the same potential.

Comment: @Karl If it's the fastest solution it may win if not it won't. We don't know.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not.
You're making two assumptions here, which could be misleading you:

1st. Life is carbon-based.
While it's true that every single life form we know of is carbon-based, this might not be the case on other planets. There's a lot of theories and speculations about other kinds of life, not based on carbon as their primary element. I'd suggest looking up "Hypothetical biochemistry" if you want more detailed informations on non-carbon life forms.

2nd. Life is multi-cellular. If you saw "Caulerpa taxifolia", you would probably think it's a plant like any other. In reality, this aquatic alga (which can grow up to 12 inches long) is a single-celled organism; the largest we know of, TBH.
That's to say that, in another world with different conditions, you might see lots of giant single-celled organisms.

Also worth mentioning, what does "life" mean? If it's "the capacity for growth, reproduction, functional activity, and continual change preceding death", then would